# How to get the list of vanished files without using additional parameters in rsync?

Tags: java, shell, unix, redhat, rsync

I'm using `rsync` command to backup a database. The `rsync` command shows the list of incremental files and then exit with `status-24`, which I believe is due to the fact that some of the files were moves, changed, deleted or merged to one.

How can I view the list of vanished files? Where does rsync logs are stored by default? I do not want to pass additional parameter to suppress the warnings or change the location of the rync log files.

Comment: Are you willing to pass parameters to enable a mode wherein output is in a format intended to be machine-parseable? Trying to parse output meant for human consumption is innately unstable (since human-formatted output can change from version to version -- humans are expected to be able to roll with the punches wrt. output format changes in a way that programmatic consumers cannot; similarly, human output changes based on locale settings, so it's not stable across all machines even within a single software release).

Comment: Beyond that, a [mcve] would do a great deal of good towards enabling someone to test their answer without guessing about the details of your scenario and how to reproduce it (and thus rolling the dice as to whether their answer is applicable at all).